# What is correlation between clocking blocks and signal assignment

Tags: interface, driver, system-verilog, uvm

Can someone explain why this two snippet of codes behave differently. In second case when i start sequence with 10 transactions i have first two transactions at the same time and one override another and it only happens at start of simulation. Everything is ok after.

```
 task fir_driver::drive_write(input fir_item#(D_WIDTH) it);
    seq_item_port.get_next_item(it);
    @mp_p.cb_fir;
    mp_p.cb_fir.i_data_sample       <= it.i_data_sample;
    seq_item_port.item_done(); 
  endtask : drive_write


  task fir_driver::drive_write(input fir_item#(D_WIDTH) it);
    seq_item_port.get_next_item(it);
    mp_p.cb_fir.i_data_sample       <= it.i_data_sample;
    @mp_p.cb_fir;
    seq_item_port.item_done(); 
  endtask : drive_write
```

Comment: can you provide definition of the clocking block as well?

Comment: clocking cb_fir @(posedge clk);
  
default input #1step output #1step;
  
output  i_data_sample, i_data_en, i_ping_pong_sel_v, i_coef_data, i_coef_we, i_coef_addr;
 
endclocking : cb_fir

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess that the last blocking event before calling `drive_write()` is not `@mp_p.cb_fir` or possibly at time 0. And there are no other blocking statements between calls to `drive_write()` Then the first drive winds up being coincident with the second drive. See Section *14.16 Synchronous Drives* in the 1800-2012 LRM.